# Why the exit function doesn't actually terminate the program

Tags: ruby, multithreading, curses

Why the second thread doesn't actually terminate the program and application still waits for the input from the first thread?

```
Curses.init_screen

first = Thread.new do
  loop {
    Curses.getch
  }
end

second = Thread.new do
  Curses.close_screen
  exit
end

second.join
first.join
```

OS -- Windows 8.

ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [x64-mingw32]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think `exit` in that scope is running [`Thread#exit`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Thread.html#method-c-exit) instead of [`Kernel#exit`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) (as you are expecting). I'm using Ruby 2.1.2, however, so perhaps the behavior is a bit different.

You can see this by running the code:

```
2.1.0 :007 > Thread.new do
2.1.0 :008 >   puts self.inspect
2.1.0 :009?> end    

main => #<Thread:0x0000010142b8f8 sleep>
```

As opposed to, if you just run `puts self.inspect` on its own (not inside a Thread):

```
2.1.0 :011 > puts self.inspect
main
 => nil
```

You should get a killed process if, instead, you explicitly call `Kernel#exit`

```
2.1.0 :001 > Thread.new do
2.1.0 :002 >   Kernel::exit
2.1.0 :003?> end
```

...which, in `irb`, will close the interactive session (kill the process).

### A simple example

If I put this in a file:

```
# test.rb

first = Thread.new do
  while 4 != 5 do
    puts gets
  end
end

second = Thread.new do
  Kernel::exit
end

second.join
first.join
```

...and from my command line:

```
$ ruby test.rb
```

...the program will immediately close, not giving me any time to provide input for the `first` thread's `gets` method call.

Whereas, if I replace that `Kernel::exit` call with `Thread::exit`, the program will never exit, but continually prompt me for input.

Possibly a difference between `2.0.0p481` as opposed to `2.1.2 [x86_64]`?

Comment: So, I need to call the Kernel#exit function manually like this -- Kernel.exit?

Comment: No, I've got the same output even in case of Kernel#exit function call

Comment: I was just trying to clarify which method is actually being called, which matters. I'll take another look at your question.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot for this! Anyway, I'm waiting for the answer

Comment: I added one more clarifying thing. There may be a difference in this case between the implementation in `2.0.0` vs `2.1.0` (which I'm using). Interesting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you find any confirmation about it, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59536/discussion-between-jefflunt-and-frozenheart).

Answer (score 1):

`exit` will kill the currently running thread, which is `second` in your case.  It will exit the process only if the current running thread is the main thread.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-c-exit)

Comment: Thanks a lot! And how can I kill the whole application?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the documentation for `exit`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/exit).  It throws `SystemExit`, so you're clobbering that one thread, but that's all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And how can I kill the whole application?

Comment: Take a look at `abort`?  Not 100% sure to be honest. :)

Comment: If I change the exit function call to abort, I see the same result